# How to specify date format in a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column filled with release dates of movies.  It is formatted as xx/xx/xx. For example 01/01/19.  What I want to do is grab only the year.  The purpose is so I can plot this data utilizing the year.

I've tried converting it using pd.to_datetime() and it returns the values like 2019-01-01 which allows me to plot it a bit cleaner, but still would rather have just the year.I also end up getting dates that are 01/01/35 converting to 2035-01-01 where it should be converting to 1935-01-01

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
print(data['release_date'].head())
0     2/20/15
1      8/6/04
2    10/10/14
3      3/9/12
4      2/5/09
Name: release_date, dtype: object

data['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['release_date'])
print(data['release_date'].head())
0   2015-02-20
1   2004-08-06
2   2014-10-10
3   2012-03-09
4   2009-02-05
Name: release_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

i've also tried specifying the origin parameter but i'm not able to figure out how it should be formatted in conjunction with the unit parameter

Comment: `data['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['release_date']).dt.year`

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

```
data['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['release_date']).dt.year
```

option 2:

```
data['release_date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['release_date']).year
```

Comment: Do you if it's possible to create upper and lower bounds for the year? I mentioned in the post that it takes a value of 35 for the year, and turns it into 2035.